# Can I purchase apps from the Amazon App Store without an Android Device?

Tags: amazon-appstore

I don't have an Android device anymore. However, I still see an app for free every now and then that I would like to have when I get a new one. Can I get apps from the Amazon Appstore without having a device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using an Android emulator such as Genymotion or the one provided by Google, you can download the Amazon Appstore on that "device" and authorize it that way. From then on, you can just get the App of the Day by visiting [this link](http://www.amazon.com/mobile-apps/b?_encoding=UTF8&node=2350149011) from your desktop browser.